# Sensor bar (Wiimote like) doesn't work

Tags: drivers, input, gamepad, joystick, wii

I recently bought a sensor bar to play Wii games on my Ubuntu 12.04, but it doesn't work. It shows as "D_R_M Magic Sport Bar" on applications, and the dmesg output is:

```
[118124.192142] input: D_R_M Magic Sport Bar  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input51
[118124.192468] generic-usb 0003:FFFF:0102.002F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [D_R_M Magic Sport Bar ] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input0
[118124.197034] input: D_R_M Magic Sport Bar  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/input/input52
[118124.197296] generic-usb 0003:FFFF:0102.0030: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [D_R_M Magic Sport Bar ] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input1
[118124.203712] input: D_R_M Magic Sport Bar  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.2/input/input53
[118124.203969] generic-usb 0003:FFFF:0102.0031: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Joystick [D_R_M Magic Sport Bar ] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2
[118124.210008] generic-usb 0003:FFFF:0102.0032: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [D_R_M Magic Sport Bar ] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input3
```

Maybe I need to install some driver to get it working properly, but I can't find it. I tried to install the drivers on Windows and it worked well.

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what device you're using specifically, but the Wii sensor bar doesn't actually do anything. It's just a few infrared LEDs spaced to the ends of the bar, and powered through the long cable that connects to the Wii. The actual "sensor" part is in the Wiimote itself, which connects to the Wii (or your computer) via Bluetooth.

It may be that the thing you're using works a bit differently, as it seems to include devices for keyboard, mouse, and joystick input, and thus may need drivers that aren't written or available for Ubuntu.